# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'u => EntityShaperExpression

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have a `List<MeterDataParameter> parameters`

When I use

```
var list = _dbContext.EnergyParameterLogs
    .Where(x => parameters.Any(u => x.DeviceId == u.Serial 
        && x.TimeStampUtc >= u.StartTimeUtc 
        && x.TimeStampUtc < u.EndTimeUtc))
    .ToList();`
```

I face the Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'u => EntityShaperExpression: 
    DataMQTT.Entities.EnergyParameterLog
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False
.DeviceId == u.Serial && EntityShaperExpression: 
    DataMQTT.Entities.EnergyParameterLog
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False
.TimeStampUtc >= (DateTime?)u.StartTimeUtc && EntityShaperExpression: 
    DataMQTT.Entities.EnergyParameterLog
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False
.TimeStampUtc < (DateTime?)u.EndTimeUtc' could not be translated.
```

Please help to solve this error. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF can't translate this kind of operation with local collection. You can try using temporary table support from [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) and perform join on those conditions. Another approach is to dynamically build the predicate either using [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/) manually or via [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)'s `PredicateBuilder`:

```cs
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<EnergyParameterLog>();
foreach (var parameter in parameters)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(log => log.DeviceId == parameter.Serial
        && log.TimeStampUtc >= parameter.StartTimeUtc
        && log.TimeStampUtc < parameter.EndTimeUtc);
}
    
var list = _dbContext.EnergyParameterLogs
    .Where(predicate)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I got similar problem, but same error, only in my case I was using only one property the ID of user.

So instead of this:

```
await _context.Users.Where(u => !Users.Any(user => user.Id == u.Id)).toListAsync()
```

Where Users is local list of User objects. I've flatten in into list of IDs and it worked :)

So the solution was:

```
await _context.Users.Where(u => !exludedUsers.Contains(u.Id)).toListAsync();
```